# How to stretch flex child in scrollable container

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I have a flexbox container with fixed width and `overflow-x: auto`. One of the childs also has fixed width, which is more than the width of container, due to this reason horizontal scrollbar appears. How to stretch the other child in the container to include scrolling area width as well?

```html
<div class="picture">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/715/800/200" width="800" height="200">
    <div class="text">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</div>
</div>
```

```css
.picture {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 600px;
    overflow-x: auto;

    border: 1px solid black;
}

.text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100px;

    color: white;
    background-color: tomato;
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/belyan/pen/eYOgOxE?editors=1100)

Comment: what do you mean , stretch another child ?

Comment: Maybe what you want to do is to set `.picture img { width: 100% }`?

Comment: okay, i did not see the background, this the normal behavior, flex or not ;) , you can go around the behavior including a wrapper that will stretch to the widest content https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/QWLdWer?editors=1100  see CSS comment about flex

Comment: Sorry for that, I made background color more contrast. You solution is working, but it seems like a trick, I mean `display: table`. I am not sure, that it is a good solution for production.

Comment: did you try setting  width to .text? vw or %

Comment: why don't you add a scroll to just the image?